# Einstein Equation at the Singularity. Understanding the Dr. Michio Kaku's explanation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities

I'm trying to understand what Dr. Michio Kaku is exaplaining in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hydDhUNvva8

I'm just able to rewrite this two equations. I think I've probably made ​​some mistake in the process of copying. Otherwise, I don't understand the meaning of the two $\mathrm O$ and the $I^{'}$ in the second equation.

In the video the Dr. Michio Kaku is solving the first equation right? But I saw that is slightly different from the classical [field equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations), why? What's the difference? $As^2$ is the solution of the first equation? Is possible understand something from the video or is it too cutted?

\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=T_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
As^2=\left(_{\mathrm O}\left(1-\frac{2MG}{r}\right)^{I^{'}\mathrm O}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: I really have no idea what this is supposed to mean. If I had to guess, I would say he was writing down the Schwarzschild Solution, which takes the form $ds^2 = - \left( 1 - \frac{2 G M}{r} \right) + \frac{dr^2}{1 - \frac{2 G M}{r}} + r^2 d \Omega^2$.

Comment: First he writes the Einstein equation, then he writes $ds^2$ and what looks to be a (sloppy) rendering of the Schwarschild metric, which is a particular solution of the Einstein equation, written as a matrix. Then he writes the head-desk equation ($1/0 = \infty$). Probably a good thing the sound isn't working.

Comment: He is writing the Schwarzschild solution in a matrix form. These O's are the zeros at the off diagonal entries of the matrix. And it is definitely "d" not an "A".

Comment: No sound in the video. Also please conform post with the meta recommendations [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4918/2451).

Comment: The first 1 minute of the video is replicated [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf0crQOlcRY) **with sound**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few errors in your transcription.

The first equation you wrote is a valid form of the Einstein field equation, but the version used by dr. Kaku does not have an equal sign. It has a tilde. I think that Dr. Kaku means that there is a relationship of proportionality there.

[image: tilde]

[image: equation]

$$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R\sim T_{\mu\nu}$$

This is Einstein's field equation.

The second equation shows the structure of a tensor, and the left term is $\mathrm{d}s^2$. The I that you see represents a 1 of the matrix and the Os are zeros.

[image: ds2]

[image: tensor]

The second equation is a succinct form of the Schartzschild solution for the Einstein equation above.

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric

Answer (score 0):

The first equation present the Einstein-Hilbert action field equation proportionality form , the second one presents the interval of of four space-time dimensions and exactly a solution for differential equation by solving it at the method of zero matrices

Comment: I think... what?